# Changing HTTP to HTTPS gives "too many redirections" error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I want to change only one page to `https`, but when I do a 301 redirect, it gives an error saying "too many redirections"?

I want to redirect "http://www.escolaedti.com.br/loja" to "https://www.escolaedti.com.br/loja"

I am using Wordpress and I tried to do this using the Redirection plugin, but it doesn't work. So I think that I have to change the `.htaccess` file.

How can I do this either in `.htaccess` or using a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with Wordpress but here is how to do it in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /loja
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=a620a51a-e09b-5b93-a6bc-69731dbd448d

Comment: have any change to broken my site with this? I mean , all my site can be redirect to https or another problem can happens???? because if this happens my site will never load =/

Comment: It shouldn't as the rewrite conditions force that 1 - the request is for not https and that 2 - the request is for /loja. That said, I would of course test this on a dev instance first since htaccess is very unforgiving towards syntax errors and the likes.

Comment: I don't follow. Could you rephrase / elaborate?